# Change application label Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to change the application label, and it does not seems to work. Its picking the default label, ie. the Activity label which has the main launcher.

I have tried the following

1. Added the following code in Manifest file:

   android:label="Application Test" within the application tag
2. Added the following code in Assembly

   [assembly: Application (Label="My App")  ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `Application Label` in `Project-Options` > `Build` > `Android Application` always work for me.

[image]

I also generally don't set value for Label in my `SplashActivity` which has `MainLauncher=true`

Comment: Thanks Sreeraj, It normally works for me with the Label in the activity. But dont know whats wrong now. But anyways, after removing the label of activity is working now. I have explicitly defined the title for the activity in my code now.